# check database row object exist or not for a given primary key?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, row

Hi
I access row object through Zend_Db_Table like

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$userTb = new Model_DbTable_Users(); //Here Model_DbTable_Users is subclass of Zend_Db_Table
$user = $userTb->find($id)->current();
```

Now how can I check using `$user` row object that whether `$id` is valid or not like what if that 'id' does not exist in database.
Earlier I used to do

```
if($user->find($id)->count() > 0 )
{
//id is valid so 
$user = $user->find($id)->current();
}
```

clearly this way is long I need short way of doing the same .

Comment: actually you jsut need to keep the result of find() = rowset somewhere. You can then use count() and current() ;) WWithout doubling the DB call. squirrel's answer is quick'n dirty way ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no rows in the rowset, `current()` returns `null`:

```
$user = $userTb->find($id)->current();
if ($user) {
    // $user is a valid row
}
else {
    // no rows found
}
```